# Popup menu is not working in options menu android

Tags: android, popupmenu, android-optionsmenu

I created options menu in android.After that I have to attach popup menu to options menu icon.in popup menu it needs anchor view but I have options menu id.So how to get anchor view from options menu id.please help me

code:

```
 switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.settings:

                PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(NavigationActivity.this,R.id.settings); ==>error 
                // Inflating the Popup using xml file
                popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, popup.getMenu());

                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
            }
            return true;
        }
```

Comment: Can you post some more code of yours, with the logcat error message you are getting? See http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2013/12/android-app-menus/  in case it helps.

Comment: actually it needs view but i don't have view to pass to popup menu PopupMenu.PopupMenu(Context context, View anchor)

Comment: This is the view below/above which you want your pop-up menu to appear. In your case the options menu. So try passing the menu option instead of its id.

Comment: you have to set view for popUp menu.

Answer (score 0):

Popup menu on option menu item click with styling:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

int id = item.getItemId();
AtomicBoolean selected = new AtomicBoolean(false);

if (id == ru.asv.dokiks.R.id.viewMenuFilter) {

  PopupMenu popupMenu =
    new PopupMenu(
      new ContextThemeWrapper(
        this,
        R.style.my_style),
      findViewById(
        ru.asv.dokiks.R.id.my_options_menu_item_view),
      Gravity.START);

  // Обработчики выбора:

  popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(
    (android.view.MenuItem item1) -> {

      if (
        item1
          .getTitle()
          .equals(
            getString(
              R.string.first_popup_menu_item))) {

        // React.
      }

      if (
        item1
          .getTitle()
          .equals(
            getString(
              R.string.second_popup_menu_item))) {

        // React.
      }

      selected.set(true);

      return true;
    });

  popupMenu.inflate(
    R.menu.my_popup_menu);

  popupMenu.show();

  selected.set(true);
}

return selected.get() || super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```